# html5 canvas transforms and caching gradient, curves, and rotations

Tags: javascript, html, optimization, canvas

I'm making a game in canvas where most of my drawings so far are solid shapes and arcs. But I want to add effects like blur and shadow to create glow and trail effects.

My question is, is there a a nice way, without external libraries, to cache the glowing element (player, enemy, etc) and is it worth it to do that instead of recreating the effects each time? Same goes for rotations. If I have about 40 different angles I draw repeatedly as a player rotates their ship, should I just cache those calculations?

I'm currently rotating the arc endings using manual transforms, instead of rotating the context since I don't yet know if that is more or less efficient than rotating the canvas repeatedly for the many onscreen elements and their different angles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blur and shadow effects are not included in the main canvas library but you may create your own library or you can use external canvas libraries like [easel.js](http://createjs.com/#!/EaselJS) but there are tons of different libraries related to HTML5 `<canvas>`. You may choose which is best suited for you.

As the matter of the blur effect you may use Mario Klingeman stackblur javascript implementation: http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html. It's easy to use and super fast.

For glowing effect a nice way for random texture generation would be the simplex noise algorithm already implemented in javascript: https://gist.github.com/304522 or the original one here: http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/noise/

For the last question i advise you for a better performance to use the `context` `save` and `restore` functionality. It's much faster.

Comment: doesnt the default canvas have shadowblur? http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-canvas-example/
I was thinking of using that and constantly changing the radius for a glowlike effect. 

And for the transforms, you're saying it's faster to translate and rotate the whole canvas for every object each frame vs just computing the transforms manually for the points on each shape that I need to be able to draw the shape?

Comment: The `shadowBlur` applies only for object's shadow and not the object/shape itself. So if you want to blur the object and not the shadow casted by, you need to write your own bluring algorithm or use other third party libraries. Translating and rotating the canvas is definitely more faster that computing the shape by skewing and rotating the transformation matrix. For even faster performance you can put the shapes which you want to transform into a separate, smaller canvas. See the test: http://jsperf.com/canvas-transform-vs-save-restore

Comment: Well my game mostly uses shapes I've defined through defining curves and and paths, and I was planning on creating the glow by using a shadowblur around the whole object.